# how to connect and select data from a JDBC over RMI database in perl?

Tags: perl, jdbc

I have a 3rd party application that exposes in-memory data structures via a JDBC api over RMI.

How can I get data out of that database api without having to run squirrel or similar GUI application?

Perl solution preferred, but java solution acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Try [DBD::JDBC](http://search.cpan.org/~vizdom/DBD-JDBC-0.71/JDBC.pod).

Comment: where does the rmi:// part come in?  is it really transparent to me?

Comment: Does it have to be over RMI?  I was guessing you could access it directly over JDBC.

Comment: It actually must be over RMI because it's a java application I'm talking to, not a real database.